# Código de erro Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","?

Tags: javascript, react

Estou com dificuldades no meu `JavaScript`, o erro dado é:

> ./src/componentes_basicos/Aleatorio.jsx
> Line 5:56:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","
> 3 |
> 4 | export default (props) => {
> 5 |     const Aleatorio = parseInt (Math.random () * {props.max} + {props.min});
> |                                                        ^
> 6 |     return (
> 7 |         
> 8 |
>
> ### O valor aleatório é {Aleatorio}

Sendo o meu código:

```
import React from 'react'


export default (props) => {
    const Aleatorio = parseInt (Math.random () * {props.max} + {props.min});
    return (
        <div>
        <h2> O valor aleatório é {Aleatorio}</h2>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Na resolução de uma operação no `javascript` com o retorno para uma variável não precisa utilizar `{}` como demonstrado no exemplo mínimo logo abaixo:

```js
function Item(props) {
    const aleatorio = 
        parseInt (Math.random () * props.max + props.min);
    return (
        <div>
          <h2> O valor aleatório é {aleatorio}</h2>
        </div>
    );
}

function App() {  
  return (
    <Item max={10} min={14} />
  );
}
ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

também pode ser passado diretamente a operação completa dentro da chaves da seguinte forma:

```js
function Item(props) {
    
    return (
        <div>
          <h2> O valor aleatório é {parseInt (Math.random () * props.max + props.min)}</h2>
        </div>
    );
}

function App() {  
  return (
    <Item max={10} min={14} />
  );
}
ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

***então***, foi utilizado de maneira errada e por isso do erro demonstrado na pergunta na linha e as chaves como problema. As chaves `{}` tem várias formas de ser utilizado até para desestruturar objetos que já é outro conceito.

Answer (score 2):

Em resumo, você está tentando criar um objeto e passar para ele a propriedade de outro objeto. Isso não faz muito sentido, pois será um objeto com uma propriedade vazia, e você está tentando multiplicar um objeto por um número e somar com outro objeto. Percebe como é confuso?

A estrutura de criação de um objeto é colocar identificadores e propriedades desses identificadores entre chaves (`{propriedade: props.max}`), e, se você tentar multiplicar esse objeto (ao invés de seus parâmetros), você irá gerar erros.

Em resumo, digamos que `props.max = 45`. Nesse caso, você está fazendo o seguinte:

```
{"45"}
```

E isso não se pode (ou ao menos não se deveria) multiplicar por qualquer outra coisa neste contexto específico (ignoremos por ora toda a sorte de operações que podemos fazer com strings, objetos e concatenações). Então, você não precisa criar um objeto, você precisa coletar o valor de dentro de um objeto já existente.

Corrigimos, dessa forma, o código removendo as chaves:

```
export default (props) => {
    const Aleatorio = parseInt (Math.random () * props.max + props.min);
    return (
        <div>
            <h2> O valor aleatório é {Aleatorio}</h2>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Se quiser compreender melhor o conceito, recomendo ler um pouco sobre [inicialização de objetos com JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Inicializador_Objeto).

[Link da solução no StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-aleatorio-1)